# MVC SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date-format

I am currently working on a new project with an existing database. When I try to load my program, the error above happens. When I checked the existing database, I found the birthday in format *yyyy/mm/dd*(e.g. 1951-03-13 00:00:00.000 ).

I tried to modify the model to

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? birthday{ get; set; }
```

but the error kept on showing. I tried doing other stuff in but still showing error. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
[image: STACK TRACE]

Comment: Please share your error .

Comment: @AnmolRathod the error is the one above. SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: You need to show the code that causes the error

Comment: @StephenMuecke I suspect that the dateformat found in the db is the one causing the error since when coding, I had no error found or else I am wrong?

Comment: Yes you are wrong (the format you see is just that - a format). The error happens if you save a date that is not in the range

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok upon browsing the database, I have found out that some value are 'NULL'. Does this trigger the said error above?

Comment: Not on its own. You need to debug you code and determine which line of your code is throwing the exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172147/discussion-between-john-clarence-castro-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Ok now I found what was causing the error, it was due to a row with a value of `<Unable to retrieve the data>`. The problem triggered the error I am experiencing. To solve this, I simply updated the row using a SQL update command.